# I'm confused with my fortran randomwalk code

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I'm working on a school project where I have to make a program that takes a random number between 1 and 0 and interprets at as left, right, or no change on a liner plot. I don't understand why the position is constant at 0. Any help?
Here it is:

```
program test
implicit none 
integer, dimension(100)::tau
integer, dimension(100)::position=0
real,dimension(100)::x
real::y,a,b
integer::n
a=1/3
b=2/3
do n=1,100
    tau(n)=n
    call random_number(y)
    x(n)=y
end do
position(1)=0
do n=1,100
  if (x(n) .le. a) then
    position(n)=position(n)+1
  else if ((x(n) .gt. a) .and. (x(n) .le. b)) then
    position(n)=position(n)-1
  else
    position(n)=position(n)+0
  end if
end do
open(unit=10, file="test.txt")
do n=1,100
    write(10,*) tau(n),x(n), position(n)
end do
close(10)
end program test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your two real variables 'a' and 'b' are defined by integer constants so they are both zero.

Change to:

```
a=1.0/3.0
b=2.0/3.0
```